# Spring mysql pool optimize

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Как оптимизировать количество коннектов из spring к mysql ?

Сейчас в файле WebAppConfig.java есть метод

```
public DataSource dataSource
```

где используется DriverManagerDataSource

и при увелечении числа пользовательских сессий к приложению, когда новая сессия начинает работать с mysql то длительное ожидание происходит получения видимо места в пуле, а как только получено место то все быстро работает.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте готовое решение 
Apache Commons dbcp и будет вам пул. Можно будет не заморачиваться и использовать готовый BasicDataSource который будет работать на дэфолтных настройках,  если захотите подогнать систему под себя то есть куча мануалов по dbcp